# How to change the width for the col-xs bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, twitter-bootstrap-4, col

Hey I find nowhere if I can change the default value of col-xs-12

I tried to put that but I all broken...

```css
.col-xs-12 {
 width: 600px;
}
```

If you are a doc where I can find the answer that will be really awesome !

Thx

Comment: What is the reason you need to change the width? The mere fact that you set a value so high does indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of the way Bootstrap works I'm afraid.

Comment: why you change it? If you changed you have some issue in responsive layout

Comment: if you want the custom width for that particular element, why use col-* at all. just use any other class and style accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never Change Bootstrap classes if you want to change any `col-` class simply add one more class on same element and style that class, and your external CSS file should be loaded after bootstrap, so the css file has effect 
Example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 my-custom-width"></div>

<style>
    .my-custom-width{
       width:600px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way

```
<div style="max-width:"600px;margin:0 auto">
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

OR with media queries

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 
.col-xs-12{
max-width:600px !important;
}
}
```