# Bootstrap 4 change width for col

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, width, col

sorry for my English, I'm new with Bootstrap....

I to want to build 4 columns and because of the width from Bootstrap  **col-sm-3** too small or **col-sm-4** too big it is, I do try as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43001427/12999026) to say, but to come as here to show

[how to show the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VxO7.png)

How to show are not margin between columns...

Code CSS

```
.container {margin-top: 13rem; }           



.product-grid{
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 170px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.product-grid:before{
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}


.product-grid .product-image a{ display: block; }
.product-grid .product-image img{
   width: 60%;
   height: auto;

}


 .product-grid { width: 300px;}


 .product-grid .product-content{
   padding: 18px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   background-color: white;
 }
 .product-grid .title{
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 500;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
 .product-grid .title a{ color: #000; }
 .product-grid .title a:hover{ color: #fa8231; }
 .product-grid .price{
    color: #fa8231;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
 }
 .product-grid .price span{
   color: #777;
   margin: 0 0 0 5px;
   font-weight: 300;

   display: inline-block;
   }
```

Code HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 product-grid"> 
        <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt=""  class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="title">
                    <a href="#">la</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="price">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 product-grid">
        <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="title">
                    <a href="#">le</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="price"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="title">
                    <a href="#">li</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="price"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
   </div><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-image">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="title">
                    <a href="#">lo</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="price"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>
   </div><br><br>
</div>
```

Can Please someone help me und this issue to solve, Thanks!

Comment: is this what you try to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/rzu67e5n/

Comment: is there any image for expectation ? the question isn't very clear. what do you mean by: How to show are not margin between columns...



What do

Comment: @G-Cyrillus 4 columns with the **width** which I to will.

Comment: @Kareem Dabbeet  yes, when trying as the link to say, I to come to the image without margins

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, yes but it is possible to separate the colour between columns? here how to want https://i.imgur.com/Nv4LEGf.png

Comment: did you understand the class used in my first example ? for the bg ?? margin all around ? https://jsfiddle.net/qnbmjr0h/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, I to do it.. https://i.imgur.com/F7AYENW.png without  `.row`  and `.row .col+.col` from your first code...

Comment: Very Thanks I wish you a nice day!